# Is there a way of running an if statement on whether or not props have changed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I currently have a component that holds a posts array, this component takes in a prop called `sortBy` which tells the component to either fetch data sorted by `popular` or `new`. The way my component is set up is upon initialization the posts are fetched then stored in redux, I only get new posts if my posts is empty. That way I'm not constantly fetching new data.

```
const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);
useEffect(() => {
    const { sortby } = props;
                            // here I would like to check if props has changed
    if (Object.keys(posts).length === 0) {
      dispatch(getPostsAsync(sortby)).then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
    }
  }, [dispatch, props, posts]);
```

Now I would like to check if the sortBy props has changed value. So originally it might be `sortby='-numLikes'` but when I sortby 'new' it should then be `sortby='-createdAt'` after it changes I would like to tell Redux to fetch new data.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to get the behavior you want is to change the useEffect to:

```js
const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);
const { sortby } = props;
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPostsAsync(sortby)).then((response) => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
}, [dispatch, sortby]);
```

Then the useEffect will run every time sortby is changed.

Comment: So i should just forget about the re-fetching of data? Right now Redux stores the data so when I change a page and come back it doesn't have to re-fetch, but I can just get rid of that I guess.

Comment: They key here is destructuring `sortby` outside the useEffect - this way you use that value as the dependency to the hook instead of `props`.

Comment: If you want to avoid re-fetching you'll need to store the sort your results are using in the redux state along with the posts. i.e.  `state = { posts, sortby }` and select the sortby via useSelect (rather than in props) then pass it as a dependency to the useEffect as above.

Comment: Or integrate react-query (or some other fetching state machine) to cache the results for you to avoid the re-fetch.